# Python - Does not exit on the third input

Tags: python

This is basic python. I want the user to enter the displayed username and password 3 times. When I entered an incorrect input in the first and second tries, the code in elif functions correctly but when I incorrectly entered it in the third try, it doesn't run the statement in the elif. Can you explain why this is happening?

The code is supposed to exit when entered the wrong input. I also want to make the user enter the correct input for 3 times then it will print the welcome.

```
username = "Username"
password = "Password"
tries = 0

print("Your username: Username")
print("Your password: Password")
print(" ")

enterusername = str(input("Enter your username:"))
enterpassword = str(input("Enter your password:"))

while tries < 2:
    if (password == enterpassword and username == enterusername):
        enterusername = str(input("Enter again your Username:"))
        enterpassword = str(input("Enter again your password:"))
        tries = tries + 1
    else:
        exit("Password or username is incorrect.")

print("Welcome")
```

Comment: The `exit` causes program to exit even at the first wrong input.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do?
You are using exit() function on incorrect username and password. which exits the program. can't understand the what you are actually doing? explain?

Comment: I want to exit the code when the inputted data is wrong. I also want to make the user enter the correct data 3 times without misspelling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic goes as follows:

- Ask for input.
- In loop:

  - Validate last input.
  - Ask new input.

You can see from this that the input form the last iteration will not be validated. You need to either:

1. Validate the first input *before* the loop and change the loop's order.
2. Validate the last input *after* the loop.

##### 1

```py
enterusername = input("Enter your username:")
enterpassword = input("Enter your password:")

if (password == enterpassword and username == enterusername):
    while tries < 2:
        enterusername = input("Enter again your Username:")
        enterpassword = input("Enter again your password:")
        if password == enterpassword and username == enterusername:
            tries += 1
        else:
            exit("Password or username is incorrect.")
else:
    exit("Password or username is incorrect.")
```

##### 2

```py
enterusername = input("Enter your username:")
enterpassword = input("Enter your password:")

while tries < 2:
    if password == enterpassword and username == enterusername:
        enterusername = input("Enter again your Username:")
        enterpassword = input("Enter again your password:")
        tries += 1
    else:
        exit("Password or username is incorrect.")

if password == enterpassword and username == enterusername:
    print("Welcome")
else:
    exit("Password or username is incorrect.")
```

---

I made a few small changes in your code:

- `input` always returns a string so there is no need to convert with `str()`.
- `x = x + 1` is equivalent to `x += 1`.
- Your condition were complementary so there is no need to write the opposite in an `elif` - just use `else`.

---

To avoid the repeated conditions, reverse the logic: check the input in the `while` condition and count the tries inside the loop:

```py
enterusername = input("Enter your username:")
enterpassword = input("Enter your password:")

while password == enterpassword and username == enterusername:
    if tries == 2:
        print("Welcome")
        break
    enterusername = input("Enter again your Username:")
    enterpassword = input("Enter again your password:")
    tries += 1
else:
    exit("Password or username is incorrect.")
```

This uses the [`while/else` construct](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) - the `else` will only be executed if the loop terminated without reaching a `break`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you set

```
while tries < 2:
```

on the third try, tries=2, so your while loop doesn't run. Change it to `while tries < 3`

Comment: But I want to limit it to the third try. It would only create a fourth input.

Comment: On correct input, this will ask the username and password 4 times which is not wanted...

Comment: I did. It  asks the input total of 4 times. And the same problem still remains: if you enter wrong input in the fourth time it still allow you to go ahead and say "Welcome"

Comment: For me the code by the OP doesn't even run correctly; when I enter a wrong input it gets stuck in the exit() forever

Comment: What does that mean? `exit` is a function. It exits the program immediately. How can it *get stuck in the exit*?

Answer (score -1):

You should put

```
while(tries <= 2):
...
```

or

```
while(tries <3):
...
```

Comment: This is already suggested in another answer and is wrong... (see comments on that answer)